# Boolean Indexing in Numpy involving two arrays

Tags: numpy

I was reading a book on Data Analysis with Python where there's a topic on Boolean Indexing.

This is the Code given in the Book:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> names = np.array(['Bob', 'Joe', 'Will', 'Bob', 'Will', 'Joe', 'Joe'])
>>> data = np.random.randn(7,4)
>>> names
array(['Bob', 'Joe', 'Will', 'Bob', 'Will', 'Joe', 'Joe'], dtype='<U4')
>>> data
array([[ 0.35214065, -0.6258314 , -1.18156785, -0.75981437],
       [-0.54500574, -0.21700484,  0.34375588, -0.99216205],
       [ 0.29883509, -3.08641931,  0.61289669,  0.58233649],
       [ 0.32047465,  0.05380018, -2.29797299,  0.04553794],
       [ 0.35764077, -0.51405297, -0.21406197, -0.88982479],
       [-0.59219242, -1.87402141, -2.66339726,  1.30208623],
       [ 0.32612407,  0.19612659, -0.63334406,  1.0275622 ]])
>>> names == 'Bob'
array([ True, False, False,  True, False, False, False])
```

Until this it's perfectly clear. But I'm unable to understand when they do data[names == 'Bob']

```
>>> data[names == 'Bob']
array([[ 0.35214065, -0.6258314 , -1.18156785, -0.75981437],
       [ 0.32047465,  0.05380018, -2.29797299,  0.04553794]])
>>> data[names == 'Bob', 2:]
array([[-1.18156785, -0.75981437],
       [-2.29797299,  0.04553794]])
```

How is this happening?

Comment: Did you read and understand https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays?

Comment: The `names=='Bob'` index is the equivalent of indexing with the list (or array) where it is True, e.g. `[0,3]`.  So it's picking rows 0 and 3.  the second version picks columns 2 and following.

Answer (score 2):

`data[names == 'Bob']`

is the same as:

`data[[True, False, False, True, False, False, False]]`

And this just means to get row 0 and row 4 from `data`.

`data[names == 'Bob',2:]`

gives the same rows, but now restricts the columns to start with column 2.  Before the comma concerns the rows, after the comma concerns the columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question?